# Как подключить blowfish?

Tags: c, криптография, blowfish

Я прочитал немного в википедии про способы симметричного шифрования, вроде, [blowfish](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F) - надежный алгоритм. Взял по [ссылке](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html) код алгоритма (Paul Kocher). Там есть пример как подключать исходники:

```
void main(void) {
    unsigned long L = 1, R = 2;
    BLOWFISH_CTX ctx;

    Blowfish_Init (&ctx, (unsigned char*)"TESTKEY", 7);
    Blowfish_Encrypt(&ctx, &L, &R);
    Blowfish_Decrypt(&ctx, &L, &R);
}
```

И все вроде бы понятно за исключением того, что такое L и R. Что они означают?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле blowfish.c ведь все написано (пункт 3):

```
Normal usage is as follows:
   [1] Allocate a BLOWFISH_CTX.  (It may be too big for the stack.)  
   [2] Call Blowfish_Init with a pointer to your BLOWFISH_CTX, a pointer to
       the key, and the number of bytes in the key.  
   [3] To encrypt a 64-bit block, call Blowfish_Encrypt with a pointer to
       BLOWFISH_CTX, a pointer to the 32-bit left half of the plaintext
       and a pointer to the 32-bit right half.  The plaintext will be
       overwritten with the ciphertext.
   [4] Decryption is the same as encryption except that the plaintext and
       ciphertext are reversed.
```